# File Manipulation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a database as a text file that looks something like:

```
Panasonic VCR 943,1998/06/30,IN,Shelf 4
Canon Camera SLR,2010/07/02,OUT,Dr. James Jones
Apple iPad,2012/01/19,IN,Shelf 19
```

How do I manipulate whats in that file once I opened it in a separate program, such as changing the IN to Out in the first line and Shelf 4 to Mr.Smith depending on which line the user selected? Do I need to do like:

```
   for i in enumerate("file"):
      i == input("line want to change")
```

Comment: [Overwriting row in same csv file using dictwriter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33968785/overwriting-row-in-same-csv-file-using-dictwriter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The couple of solutions provided above are decent. Here's a little more descriptive method:

```
import fileinput
import sys

filename = 'test.txt'

# ----
# print the line user asked for
def printline(linenumber):
    handle = open(filename)
    for i, line in enumerate(handle):
        if (i+1) == int(linenumber):
            print (line)
            # find a keyword to type here to exit for loop as soon as the line of interest is printed
    handle.close()

# ----

# ask user for the line number
linenumber = input('Please enter line number: ')
print ('Line %s is: ' % linenumber)
printline(linenumber)

# ask if IN/OUT has to be changed
answer = input('Switch IN to OUT --OR-- OUT to IN? (y/n): ');
if answer == 'y':

    # use fileinput to change the file in place
    for line in fileinput.input(filename, inplace = True):

        # if it is the line of interest, switch IN to OUT if ,IN, is found
        # switch OUT to IN if ,OUT, is found
        if fileinput.filelineno() == int(linenumber):
            if ',IN,' in line:
                print ('%s' % line.strip().replace(',IN,', ',OUT,'))
            else:
                print ('%s' % line.strip().replace(',OUT,', ',IN,'))

        # if this is not the right line, just print the line back to file
        else:
            print (line.strip())

    fileinput.close()

print ('Line %s is: ' % linenumber)
printline(linenumber)

print ('Done')
```

Result:

```
$ /c/Python34/python.exe test.py
Please enter line number: 2
Got it. Line 2 is:
Canon Camera SLR,2010/07/02,IN,Dr. James Jones

Switch IN to OUT --OR-- OUT to IN? (y/n): y
Line 2 is:
Canon Camera SLR,2010/07/02,OUT,Dr. James Jones

Done
```

You should definitely invest time to improve on this based on other answers and reading the docs.

Answer (score 0):

```
line = input("line want to change")
with open('file.txt', 'r+') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for idx, row in enumerate(spamreader):
        if idx == line:
            do what you want

Then rewrite the change to the file
```

Comment: csv reader may better for access the item in specific columns

Answer (score 0):

Convert the file into list, then you can enjoy the convenience of Python. Once you are done with the processing, the list again can be saved as file.

```
with open("/Users/neo/test.txt", "rw") as file:
    file = [line.strip() for line in file]
    i = input("Enter the line #: ")
    print file[i]
```

Here will be the usage

```
> python ~/test.py
Enter the line #: 2
Apple iPad,2012/01/19,IN,Shelf 19
```